# wp_insert_post doesnt show in WP Admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

so i want to add post programatically with my plugin, i write this code:

```
    $my_post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'My post',
    'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
    'post_status'   => 'draft',
    'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_category' => array(1)
  );

  // Insert the post into the database
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

and this is return post ID to variable but post doesnt show in wp admin posts table. WordPress is counting this like new post but doesnt show. Why?

Comment: try to see if it displays an error - and be sure, that you haven't set your dashboard to only show published posts

Comment: `if(!is_wp_error($post_id)){
  //the post is valid
}else{
  //there was an error in the post insertion, 
  echo $post_id->get_error_message();
}`

Comment: I changed the code structure to most structural and probably this’ll work, I will check it in home and give feedback. C’ya

Comment: okay, so the form must be send to admin-post.php and after that magic happens in wordpress hooks, i tried add post before wordpress is loaded and that is why isn't working properly